# PyTorch dataset transform normalization nb_samples += batch_samples IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-2, 1], but got 2)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, pytorch-dataloader

***Goal:*** find the mean and std tensors to use in `transforms.Normalize` part of `data_transforms`

***Doubt:*** do we need to have three different mean and std tensors for each of the train, val, and test sets?

***Error:*** not sure how to apply the code in PyTorch forum to my dataloader. Below is the error and code.

I have images that are not natural images and I am planning to use Inception V3 pretrained ImageNet for fine-tuning.

I have [this code](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html#inception-v3) (with some slight modification/addition) from PyTorch training and [Piotr's code here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/about-normalization-using-pre-trained-vgg16-networks/23560/6). However, I get an error:

```
# Create training and validation datasets
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x), data_transforms[x]) for x in ['train', 'val', 'test']}
# Create training and validation dataloaders
print('batch size: ', batch_size)
dataloaders_dict = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4) for x in ['train', 'val', 'test']}
mean = 0.
std = 0.
nb_samples = 0.
for data in dataloaders_dict['train']:
    print(print(len(data)))
    print("data[0] shape: ", data[0].shape)
    batch_samples = data[0].size(0)
    
    data = data[0].view(batch_samples, data[0].size(1), -1)
    mean += data[0].mean(2).sum(0)
    std += data[0].std(2).sum(0)
    nb_samples += batch_samples

mean /= nb_samples
std /= nb_samples
```

I assume, I need to use similar code as above for also `dataloaders_dict['val']` and `dataloaders_dict['test']`. Please correct me if I am wrong. Anyhow, the error is:

```
batch size:  512
2
None
data[0] shape:  torch.Size([512, 3, 299, 299])


 IndexError Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [19], in <module> **24** batch_samples = data[0].size(0) **26** data = data[0].view(batch_samples, data[0].size(1), -1) ---> 27 mean += data[0].mean(2).sum(0) **28** std += data[0].std(2).sum(0) **29** nb_samples += batch_samples IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-2, 1], but got 2)
```

[image]

For now, I have commented the "Normalize" part of data transform and using it only for resizing matter. I am not sure how exactly Data Transform should look like if we have the initial goal of calculating mean and std tensors. Please let me know if it is wrong.

```
input_size = 299 # for Inception V3

data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(input_size),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        #transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(input_size),
        transforms.CenterCrop(input_size),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        #transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
    
    'test': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(input_size),
        transforms.CenterCrop(input_size),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        #transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_mean_std(loader):
    # VAR[X] = E[X**2] - E[X]**2
    channels_sum, channels_squared_sum, num_batches = 0, 0, 0
    for data, _ in loader:
        channels_sum += torch.mean(data, dim=[0,2,3])
        channels_squared_sum += torch.mean(data**2, dim=[0,2,3])
        num_batches += 1
    
    mean = channels_sum/num_batches
    std = (channels_squared_sum/num_batches - mean**2)**0.5
    return mean, std
```

```
train_mean, train_std = get_mean_std(dataloaders_dict['train'])
print(train_mean, train_std)
```

tensor([0.7031, 0.5487, 0.6750]) tensor([0.2115, 0.2581, 0.1952])

```
test_mean, test_std = get_mean_std(dataloaders_dict['test'])
print(test_mean, test_std)
```

tensor([0.7048, 0.5509, 0.6763]) tensor([0.2111, 0.2576, 0.1979])

```
val_mean, val_std = get_mean_std(dataloaders_dict['val'])
print(val_mean, val_std)
```

tensor([0.7016, 0.5549, 0.6784]) tensor([0.2099, 0.2583, 0.1998])

Took from this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6IEcEBRZks)

Comment: not sure about correctness fully and also not sure what `dim=[0,2,3]` represents